# Pointer seems not be sync with printf's output

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, strcpy, pointer-arithmetic

I have trouble understanding what `pointer2` contains. The second `printf` prints `llo World`, but the third one prints `Hey you guys!`. Why would it be like that if `strcpy` copies `y you guys!\n` into `llo World`. From my understanding of the below program the last output supposed to be `llo Worldy you guys!\n`, isn't it?

```c
int main() 
{
    char str_a[20];  // a 20 element character array
    char *pointer;   // a pointer, meant for a character array
    char *pointer2;  // and yet another one

    strcpy(str_a, "Hello World\n");

    pointer = str_a; // set the first pointer to the start of the array
    printf("%p\n", pointer);

    pointer2 = pointer + 2; // set the second one 2 bytes further in
    printf("%s", pointer2);       // print it

    strcpy(pointer2, "y you guys!\n"); // copy into that spot
    printf("%s", pointer);        // print again
}
```

Comment: Firstly, welcome to the StackOverflow. The `pointer2` holds the address of the first `l` in `Hello World` string. After printing it once, the data it points to is being overwritten by the string `y you guys`! The string is written to the memory starting from the `pointer2`

Comment: Why would you expect, `strcpy` to append the string at the end? Besides that, your array can only hold 20 characters. You expect it to hold more than that.

Comment: @CaglayanDOKME How does `pointer` gets modified though? `strcpy` doesn't mess with it.

Comment: `pointer` is not modified. It points to `str_a`, similar as `pointer2` points into the array. That array is modified.

Comment: @Gerhardh I think I have misconception about what `pointer + 2` actually does.. What part of the string does it take, the `He` or the rest?

Comment: nvm boys. thx you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer `pointer` points to the first character of the array `str_a`.

```
pointer = str_a;
```

The array contains the string `"Hello World\n"`.

The pointer `pointer2` points to the third element of the string

```
pointer2 = pointer + 2;
```

that is it points to `"llo World\n"`.

Then this substring is overwritten keeping unchanged `str_a[0]` and `str_a[1]`.

```
strcpy(pointer2, "y you guys!\n");
```

So the array `str_a` contains the string `"Hey you guys!\n"`

In fact the above call of strcpy is equivalent to

```
strcpy( &str_a[2], "y you guys!\n");
```

because in turn this statement

```
pointer2 = pointer + 2;
```

is equivalent to

```
pointer2 = &str_a[2];
```

or

```
pointer2 = &pointer[2];
```

And this call

```
printf("%s", pointer);
```

outputs the string.

That is `"He"` (starting from str_a[0]) plus `"y you guys!\n"` (starting from `str_a[2]`)yields the result string.

Comment: Where does the `He` waits? Why is `He` being added and not the rest of the string that was cut by `pointer2`?

Comment: @userfaultfd The elements of the array str_a[0] and str_a[1] were not overwritten. The new string was written starting from str_a[2]. And the pointer pointer outputs the result array starting from str_a[0].

Comment: Yep, I understand now. My problem was that I thought that a pointer is an object by itself. I didn't know that by `strcpy`ing a pointer the place it is pointing is also changed. Gotta go back to pointers ig.

Comment: @userfaultfd: A pointer is an object by itself, one that points at another object,  `strcpy` changes the object pointed at by the pointer, not the pointer (it remains unchanged)

Answer (score 0):

```
char str_a[20];  // a 20 element character array
char *pointer;   // a pointer, meant for a character array
char *pointer2;  // and yet another one
```

The first line creates and allocates memory to 20 characters.
The other two only create pointers to nothing. These pointers can be used to point to a memory region, what means that you can store an address (number) inside them.

```
strcpy(str_a, "Hello World\n");
```

This line copy "Hello World\n" to **str_a** (an allocated memory - OK).

```
pointer = str_a; // set the first pointer to the start of the array
printf("%p\n", pointer);
```

Now, we copy the address of **str_a** to **pointer** variable. These two variables can be used the same way. They point to the same memory. The memory address pointed is printed.

```
pointer2 = pointer + 2; // set the second one 2 bytes further in
printf("%s", pointer2);       // print it
```

Here we copy an address (a number) too, like it was done before, but we add 2 to de address. So, if **str_a** and **pointer** point to a position X, now, **pointer2** will point to X+2 (X is a number, the memory address of the block). We know that this block (**str_a**) has the content "Hello World\n", and then, **pointer2** points to a position 2 chars to right: "llo World\n". This only means the address number stored by **pointer2** points to this position, but the allocated block contains the whole sentence yet.

```
strcpy(pointer2, "y you guys!\n"); // copy into that spot
printf("%s", pointer);        // print again
```

Now, we can see a copy of characters to the address pointed by **pointer2**. So, the first two characters are outside of the copy location, and "y you guys!\n" will be copied to position 2 of **str_a**, that is position 0 of **pointer2**.

The result: "He" (two first characters of **str_a** untouched) + "y you guys!\n" (the copied characters to **pointer2**) = "Hey you guys!\n"

If you print **pointer2**, you will see "y you guys!\n".

Comment: Thank you, Alex. I understand much more now.